# What is the purpose for Java JNLP requiring a signature?

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, jnlp

I have only a limited understanding of security basics and things like digital signatures.  I understand, for example, how digital signatures are useful in public key cryptography.  I do not, however, understand why signing my JNLP is necessary, or what maliciousness it prevents against, nor can I find this info readily available.

I have found that deploying unsigned JNLP's is allowed, but things like disk and network access are restricted.  However, let's assume I am a malicious person who makes a Java application that will do something malicious to the content of your disk (and I disguise it as something else).  I can easily sign this, deploy it, and you can come to my website, unsuspecting, and launch the app and have your disk attacked.  In a case like this... what did the signature accomplish?

More to the point... if anyone can simply sign an application with hardly any effort required... then what's the point?

I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious... please enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *just* sign something - not if you want the browser to execute it without restrictions. The certificate that you use to sign your software must be signed using another certificate, and so on, until the [*chain of trust*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust) reaches a [*root certificate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate) that has been installed in your browser.

While there *have* been a few less than diligent [Certificate Authorities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Authority) occasionally, you cannot generally get such a certificate without providing some proof of your (network) identity. That means that malicious people have to provide some sort of identification, little as it may be. Even more important, CAs are expected to [revoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list) certificates that have been used for malicious activities, or otherwise compromised, thus limiting the extent of the exposure.

To get to your point, if you use a CA-signed certificate in your site and that certificate is used to distribute malicious software, the CA will revoke your certificate sooner rather than later. If, on the other hand, you use a self-signed certificate, the browser will ask the user to confirm its use. If the user goes through with it despite the warning, well, it's their own fault, *ain't it*? There is no general countermeasure to either stupidity or ignorance, after all...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I sort of understand what you're saying.  But I guess I was referring mainly to self-signing.  I just self-signed my application which as you pointed out, allows the application to run from my website if the user agrees to it after receiving a "warning."  So why can't it also present the user with the same warning and option to run an **unsigned** application?  My self-signed application seems to be just as trustworthy as an unsigned one.  Only difference is I have to go through additional work to self-sign it.  What's the point?

Comment: And I don't think a user would be incredibly foolish to click through the warning on my site, anymore than he would be if he downloaded an executable jar/exe and ran it himself (which we all do every day with free and open source apps... unless you read the entire source code for each of them).  That is what irks me the most I guess... to download/run a JAR, no signature is needed.  But to click a JNLP (which does the exact same thing - download/run a JAR)... you must have a signature.  It doesn't add up.

Comment: *"So why can't it also present the user with the same warning and option to run an **unsigned** application?"* An unsigned application will be sand-boxed.  Only apps. which intend to do actions prevented by the sand-box need to be digitally signed.  **Note** If that is your question, I'll enter this comment as an answer.  If it is not your question, I'd probably vote to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Apologies if the question is not clear.  To comment on your answer, it appears that a self-signed application can be run out of the sandbox if the user allows it.  My question is, since a self-signed app has as much inherent trustworthiness as an unsigned app (i.e., none), why can't the unsigned app also be run outside of a sandbox if the user allows it?  What is the point of limiting unsigned apps to the sandbox, but letting self-signed apps out, when **anyone** can indeed _just_ self-sign an app.

Comment: *"What is the point of limiting unsigned apps to the sandbox"*  As an end user, I don't want to be prompted to accept code that might wipe my disks and upload my personal data to someone else.  Being 'not prompted' is a good indication that the (unsigned) applet can do nothing harmful.  I don't think it helps here to consider 'self-signed' code.  Self-signed code should not go into production.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I guess it depends what you mean by "into production."  I've seen very big successful open source projects that use a self-signed JNLP on their webpage (JOSM, for example).  It seems silly to requiring them to self-sign their application so that their thousands of users can use it... when the self-signing itself proves nothing.  The users use it because they trust the publisher.  I'm not sure what is bad about considering this case.  As a developer of a new open-source app myself, self-signing is the only real option for my JNLP.  I can't afford anything fancier.

Comment: *"I've seen very big successful open source projects that use a self-signed JNLP on their webpage"*  That doesn't make it a good idea.  Note that I offer many 'self-signed' apps. as well, but like I said, they really *should* be signed with a valid certificate.  If such certificates were reasonably priced, my apps. would use them.  What exactly does your app. do that requires trust?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hrm, it appears I was mistaken and my app does work without the self-signing.  Oops.  My confusion still remains.  That a web-clicked JNLP _could_ require a signature, but the same JAR when downloaded will run fine _without_ any signature, still seems strange.  I guess maybe it is because the reasonable expectation of a web link is that it would not have the same privileges as a downloaded program file.

Comment: Whether an app. will work in a sand-box really comes down to what it tries to do.  E.G. If it requires access to the local disks or contacting a site that is not the 'home server' - it will require trust.

Comment: @AndrewThompson And I take it back.  I was incorrect, again.  My app does still require the signature, and it's because of local disk access.  Is my idea at all correct about why a "web-clicked" app requires a signature but a downloaded binary of the same program does not?

Answer (score 1):

This question does raise some valid points and thkala provided a good defense for the value of CAs that are issued from a trusted authority.

But why do we need a CA for a JNLP and not for a regular execuatbale JAR file? I think the reason is that JNLP is meant to be launched from a browser. JNLP files are a replacement for applets that run withing the browser in a sandbox - theoretically secured away from doing any harm on your computer. A user may launch a jar file running in an applet simply by visiting a page. Likewise, a JNLP may be launched by simply clicking a button. In Chrome I get asked to first save the JNLP. But in IE or Firefox, I see a launch button or regular web link - it looks like any other button or link in a web page - and with a click the program runs. This is a bit more seemless than downloading an executable and then running it.

On the other hand, an executable JAR file can be installed or just run a number of ways. For instance, they are often packaged on CDs along with MRIs since some MRI viewing software runs on the JVM and the patient or doctor needs to launch the custom software to view the MRI. But this software doesn't get "installed." You simply run it from the CD.

A JNLP on the other hand can work more like an installer than a stand alone program. I've been able to get them to create desktop shortcuts and do file associations. From the users perspective, my JNLP app feels like a native program with it's own icon and file type. Since it runs so seemelessly from the browser and has unfettered access to the client PC, having it "signed and trusted" can make users feel more secure in running this.

Historically, I believe this is why JNLP and applets get signed. **I believe the practical value of this signing has expired.**

First of all, signing your app from a CA costs hundreds of dollars so many companies skip this. There are some cooperate apps that run self-signed code and the users just know to click the "accept" button after the browser gives the warning.

More importantly, the recent security updates for Java have centered around patching back doors that allow **unsigned code** to get out of the sandbox and do everything that a signed applet or JNLP can do. It seems that every time Oracle patches a way out of the sandbox, someone finds a different way out. The best solution is to have the runtime **always prompt** the user for permission to run a Java applet or JNLP file. Not only can a self-signed JNLP file gain access to the local file system and the LAN, but an unsigned JNLP can as well.  If the user has the very latest security update from Oracle (of course, most do not) and before the next clever way to slip out of the sandbox is discovered, then the sandbox model is really working as intended. But for most users, most of the time, the sanbox model has not been working as intended. I think it's time for all JNLP files to ask for permission to run and just given them all the same access that a regular JAR file has.

Then I won't have to re-create my security certificate every 6 months.